# Available push topic records

Tags: apex, limits

In Apex code, how can I fetch the [available number of topics (PushTopic records)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/limits.htm) per Org so I don't hit its limit?
I know there's [a helper class for limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm), but I don't think it mentions push topics.

Comment: Have you tried simply querying `SELECT count() FROM PushTopic`?

Comment: that can work but I'd have to hardcode the governor limits, right? they can vary in the present (from org to org) and in the future (if Salesforce changes them)